# How do I store a rowversion values in a table that already has a rowversion column?

Tags: sql-server, rowversion

I have a two tables (`Users`, `DeletedUsers`) and a trigger `Users_Delete`. When a user record is deleted I want to store the id and the last `rowversion` value (before it was deleted) in the `DeletedUsers` table.

Because SQL does not allow multiple columns of type `rowversion` on a table, how should I store the `LastUserVersion` in the `DeletedUsers` table? What datatype should I use?

Sample Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Version] [rowversion] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeletedUsers] (
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LastUserVersion] [rowversion] NOT NULL,    -- ERROR
    [Version] [rowversion] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Users_Delete] ON [dbo].[Users]
    AFTER DELETE
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DeletedUsers]
    (
        ObjectID,
        LastUserVersion
    )
    SELECT
        ObjectID,
        Version
    FROM DELETED
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I store a rowversion values in a table that already has a
>   rowversion column?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx):

> A nonnullable rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a
>   binary(8) column. A nullable rowversion column is semantically
>   equivalent to a varbinary(8) column.

Because the definition of `[rowversion]` column is `[Version] [rowversion] NOT NULL` you could use `BINARY(8)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a point in keeping a rowversion of a deleted row. Besides, you are not only limited to one rowversion column per table, you are also not allowed to insert or update that column.

That said, rowversion is Binary(8), so you can use that. Basically, it is a number, so you can convert it to an integer which may be more convenient. For 8 Byte, you will need bigint.

Comment: Let's say I have a one-to-many relationship between `CarOwners` and `Cars`. I want to retrieve all `CarOwners` whose collection of `Cars` have changed (modified, inserted, deleted) after a certain rowversion value. Without storing the last rowversion of the `Car` in the deleted table, the `CarOwner` would be excluded from the result set if that was the only change to its collection.

Comment: hmm.. now I am thinking I don't need it. There is no reasonable scenario where the value of the rowversion on a `DeletedUsers` record will ever be incremented again, so I can just use the rowversion values that already exist on that table.